# How can I have a placeholder for a dropdown menu disappear when clicked and reappear if the user doesn't click an option?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dropdown, placeholder

Trying to make it so month and gender placeholders disappear when clicked and reappear if no dropdown input clicked.

I have sort of achieved it, however it is by adding it as a disabled option, but this looks ugly as there is a blank option in the list.

How can I make it so the placeholder achieves the functionality as described, but not by having an ugly empty option in the dropdown.

```
import React from 'react';

export const BirthdayAndGenderComponent = ({
    month, 
    handleMonthClick,
    handleMonthBlur,
    handleSelectMonth,
    monthPlaceholder,
    day,
    dayPlaceholder,
    handleDayClick,
    handleDayBlur,
    handleSelectDay,
    year,
    yearPlaceholder,
    handleYearClick,
    handleYearBlur,
    handleSelectYear,
    gender,
    handleGenderBlur,
    handleGenderClick,
    handleSelectGender,
    genderPlaceholder
}) => {
    
    return (
        <form>

            <h1 class="thin space">Basic Information</h1>

            <h2 class='thin gap'>Enter your birthday and gender</h2>

            <div class='third-container'>
                <label class="space line-height dob-input-width">
                    <select class='input-third-adjust select-color' value={month} onChange={handleSelectMonth} onClick={handleMonthClick} onBlur={handleMonthBlur}>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="January">January</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="February">February</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="March">March</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="April">April</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="May">May</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="June">June</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="July">July</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="August">August</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="September">September</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="October">October</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="Novemeber">Novemeber</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="December">December</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value={month} disabled={month === ""}>
                            {month || monthPlaceholder}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </label>

                <label class="space line-height dob-input-width">
                    <input 
                        class='input-third'
                        type='number' 
                        value={day} 
                        onChange={handleSelectDay} 
                        placeholder={dayPlaceholder}
                        onFocus={handleDayClick}
                        onBlur={handleDayBlur}
                    />
                </label>

                <label class="space line-height dob-input-width">
                    <input 
                        class='input-third'
                        type='number' 
                        value={year} 
                        onChange={handleSelectYear} 
                        placeholder={yearPlaceholder}
                        onFocus={handleYearClick}
                        onBlur={handleYearBlur}
                    />
                </label>
            </div>

            
     
            <label class="space line-height gender-input-width">
                    <select class='input-third-adjust select-color' value={gender} onChange={handleSelectGender} onClick={handleGenderClick} onBlur={handleGenderBlur}>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="Female">Female</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="Male">Male</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="Rather ">Rather not say</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value="Custom">Custom</option>
                        <option className="select-dropdown-options" value={gender} disabled={gender === ""}>
                            {gender || genderPlaceholder}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                </label>
            
            <section class='button-right'>
                {/* { <button class="space blue-button" handleNextClick={handleNextClick}>
                    Next   
                </button> }   */}
                { <button class="space blue-button">
                    Next   
                </button> } 
            </section>

        </form>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BirthdayAndGenderComponent } from '../components/BirthdayAndGenderComponent';

export const BirthdayAndGenderContainer = () => {

    const [month, setMonth] = useState('');
    const [day, setDay] = useState("");
    const [year, setYear] = useState("");
    const [gender, setGender] = useState("");
    const [monthPlaceholder, setMonthPlaceholder] = useState("Month");
    const [dayPlaceholder, setDayPlaceholder] = useState("Day");
    const [yearPlaceholder, setYearPlaceholder] = useState("Year");
    const [genderPlaceholder, setGenderPlaceholder] = useState("Gender");

// Month

    const handleMonthClick = () => {
        setMonthPlaceholder("");
    };

    const handleMonthBlur = () => {
        if (month === "") {
            setMonthPlaceholder("Month");
        }
    };

    const handleSelectMonth = (event) => {
        setMonth(event.target.value);
        setMonthPlaceholder("");
    };

// Day

    const handleDayClick = () => {
        setDayPlaceholder("");
    };

    const handleDayBlur = () => {
        if (day === "") {
            setDayPlaceholder("Day");
        }
    };

    const handleSelectDay = (event) => {
        setDay(event.target.value);
    };


// Year

    const handleYearClick = () => {
        setYearPlaceholder("");
    };

    const handleYearBlur = () => {
        if (year === "") {
            setYearPlaceholder("Year");
        }
    };

    const handleSelectYear = (event) => {
        setYear(event.target.value);
    };

// Gender

    const handleGenderClick = () => {
        setGenderPlaceholder("");
    };

    const handleGenderBlur = () => {
        if (gender === "") {
            setGenderPlaceholder("Gender");
        }
    };

    const handleSelectGender = (event) => {
        setGender(event.target.value);
    };



    return (

        <BirthdayAndGenderComponent
            month={month}
            monthPlaceholder={monthPlaceholder}
            handleMonthClick={handleMonthClick}
            handleMonthBlur={handleMonthBlur}
            handleSelectMonth={handleSelectMonth}
            day={day}
            dayPlaceholder={dayPlaceholder}
            handleDayClick={handleDayClick}
            handleDayBlur={handleDayBlur}
            handleSelectDay={handleSelectDay}
            year={year}
            yearPlaceholder={yearPlaceholder}
            handleYearClick={handleYearClick}
            handleYearBlur={handleYearBlur}
            handleSelectYear={handleSelectYear}
            gender={gender}
            genderPlaceholder={genderPlaceholder}
            handleGenderBlur={handleGenderBlur}
            handleGenderClick={handleGenderClick}
            handleSelectGender={handleSelectGender}
        />

    )

}
```

If you need anything from me to get this solved, please ask.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Jake